# Remove gap between ListViews Xamarin form

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have 3 `listViews` on one page, I am getting a gap between every `listview` and I don't know why its getting spaces.

Here is my code:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollView >
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" 
                      SeparatorColor="Red" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding GetAssignedTask}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                         BackgroundColor="White"  >
                                <Image Source="rsz_pnglogocom.png"  />
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="Task 1" 
                                           TextColor="Black" 
                                           FontSize="Medium" />
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Label Margin="0,0,70,0" 
                                               Text="{Binding dtStart,StringFormat='{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}'}"  
                                               TextColor="Red" 
                                               HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                        <Label Text="Waqas" 
                                               TextColor="Black" 
                                               HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="test"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" 
                      SeparatorColor="Red" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding GetAssignedTask}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                         BackgroundColor="LightPink"  >
                                <Image Source="rsz_pnglogocom.png"  />
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="Task 1" 
                                           TextColor="Black" 
                                           FontSize="Medium" />
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Label Margin="0,0,70,0"
                                               Text="{Binding dtStart,StringFormat='{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}'}"  
                                               TextColor="Red" 
                                               HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                        <Label Text="Waqas" 
                                               TextColor="Black" 
                                               HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

I need to get rid of this spaces and display `listview` one after another, you can check image down below how it's displaying `listviews`.

[image: lISTviews gap]

Anyone can tell me how to remove these spaces?

Comment: It seems like you don't really need 3 listviews. Except for the background color, the views have the same data and layout. What's exactly your intention about this layout?

Comment: i need to show 3 listview as every listview binding different data ah my  code shows same binding for listview, but its not i have different binding for every listview

Comment: I don't think it'll be usable (or without some platform rendering implementation I doubt its even possible). The `ListView` has a Height and an Inner 'scroll panel', that owns the items. The listviews have no gap between each other, the 'gap' is between the unused space of the first listview (not enough items) and the beginning of the second one.

Comment: You should resort to use a grouped listview or handle `ItemTemplates` for each kind of data you want to show.

Comment: how can i set height and scroll for 3 listviews to display in page

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Comment: so what will be best solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50405791/remove-gap-between-listviews-xamarin-form?noredirect=1#comment87891611_50405791

Comment: well thanks for your guidance and i have set every listview with height and scroll

Answer (score 2):

> Application developers should not nest one ScrollView within another.
>   Additionally, they should refrain from nesting them other elements
>   that can scroll, such as WebView.

Source: official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView?view=xamarin-forms#remarks).

Nested ScrollViews are disaster just don't do that.
Which control will get scrolled on a user interaction? It will totally ruin the UX, performance and etc.

The space here is the smallest problem as you understand. You have to rethink your UI. You can replace the ScrollView by a single grouped ListView for example. Alternatively replace the top level `ScrollView` by a `Grid` which will have 2 `ListViews` not nested in each other.

Back to your original question, shared `XAML` example has a lot of unnecessary nodes, I would recommend to flatten it. For example instead of having multiple `StackLayouts` organise the layout by a single `Grid` with multiple rows. This way it will be more performant and your issue will be resolved or at least easier to understand and resolve.